# Webpack Image File Not Showing

Tags: javascript, webpack

With the following directory structure and webpack config file, I cannot get the images path to show or refer to them in css/js. From what I know, this should be accessible in `./assets/images/filename.ext` but what is preventing it?

file structure of src:

```
.
├── src
│   ├── assets
│   │   └── images
│   │       └── close.png
│   ├── js
│   ├── scss
│   └── templates
```

file rules of webpack.config.js:

```
{
  test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      limit: 25000,
      name: 'assets/images/[name].[ext]'
    },
  },
},
{
  test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: 'assets/images/[name].[ext]'
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this once:

```
/^[^\/]+\/assets\/?(?:[^\/]+\/?)*$/gm
```

you also check [here](https://regex101.com/r/gO4eS8/264)

Comment: but it showing where I checked and also give reference to check in answer too